# Laravel 4.1 ReflectionException

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4

I get the following error from Laravel 4.1.

**ReflectionException
Class Acme\Services\TaskCreatorService does not exist.**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Below is the code defining the class. It is found in `app\Acme\Services`.

---

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services;

use \Acme\Validators\TaskValidator;
use \Acme\Validators\ValidationException;
use \Acme\Validators\Validator;

class TaskCreatorService {

    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(TaskValidator $validator) {

        $this->validator = $validator;

    }

    public function make(array $attributes) {

        //determone whether data is valid
        if ($this->validator->isValid($attributes)) {
        Task::create([
            'title' => $attributes['title'],
            'body' => $attributes['body'],
            'user_id' => $attributes['assign']
         ]);

        return true;
        }

        throw new ValidationException('Task validation failed', $this->validator-getErrors());
        //create the new task
        //
        //if not throw exception
    }
}
```

I have also add this to `composer.json` in the autoload section.

```
    "psr-0": {
        "Acme": "app/"
    }
```

Comment: Seems like whatever code is trying to use your class isn't configured to autoload that namespace

Comment: As Antonio says below, while you don't need to do a `composer dump-autoload` in general when using PSR-0/4, you will need to do it the first time you edit the `composer.json` file to specify this, just so that Composer actually knows about this PSR rule. Is that the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your PSR-0 namespace

```
"Acme": "app/"
```

Your class file must be:

```
/var/www/appdir/app/Acme/Services/TaskCreatorService.php
```

And you have to

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Once, when you created the PSR-0 namespace. Check the file

```
/var/www/appdir/vendor/composer/autoload_psr0.php
```

And check if your namespace is there.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I was missing a freaking comma after adding a file in composer.json. Lesson learned to go over my code with a fresh mind!

Answer (score 1):

For me, in my case, following did work!

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I found it with a little explanation in the following [link](http://www.elcoderino.com/reflectionexception-class-someclass-does-not-exist-laravel-4/)

Hope it will be helpful!

Laravel is really harder for newbies to catch up with, specially for the people who don't know Symfony or Ruby-on-Rails techniques!

Good Luck guys!